# InfluxDB: metadata for entire series?

Tags: influxdb

I have many series in InfluxDB.  I'd like to designate them as 'a' or 'b' series'.  I know there are tags for the data within the series, but is there a way to have metadata for the series itself?  Or do I need to store this in another RDB?

Comment: I can think of several different things your question might mean. Can you give a small example to illustrate and clarify what you mean?

Comment: If you could open up a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) detailing your use case, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelDesa - I've seen a feature request someone made about this online, awhile back.  It was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common question I get from people about InfluxDB. At the moment you'll need an external DB to handle this kind of information.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? Are there now possibilities for storing metadata (like. configs) within the influxdb?